# Proof that infinite product of 1 - a_m converges

Tags: number-theory

Let $0 < a_m < 1$ be a real sequence of numbers, where $m \geq 1,$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_m$ converges. Show this implies $\displaystyle\prod_{m=1}^{\infty} (1 - a_m)$ converges to a nonzero number.

So I've written the partial product and sum respectively as $\displaystyle P_M = \prod_{m=1}^{M} (1 - a_m)$ and $\displaystyle S_M = \sum_{m=1}^{M} a_m$.

I have the result that $P_M \leq e^{- S_M}$ but I don't feel like this will be that helpful, since we already know that $P_M \leq 1.$

I know the result follows from a lemma to do with absolute convergence, but this lemma isn't provided in my module, and my lecturer said that the proof was similar to the proof of the fact that if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges where $b_n \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}, n \geq 1$ iff $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 + b_n)$ converges. The proof of this is essentially, you define the partial product and sum similarly, and note that $S_M < P_M < e^{S_M}$ so the result follows.

Comment: Take the $\log$.

Comment: [*Hint*] Discarding first finite sums, we can assume that $\sum a_n < 1/2$. By induction, you may show that \begin{equation}1-S\le 1-S_N\le P_N.\end{equation} Can you do this from here?

Comment: @Riemann I'm a bit confused, how can we assume that the sum of a_n is less than 1/2?

Comment: Since $\sum a_n$ converges, there is a natural number $M$ s.t $\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}a_n < 1/2$. To determine convergence of $P_N$, it suffices to check for large terms, and for $N>M$, $P_N = P_{M}\cdot\prod_{n=M+1}(1-a_n)$ where $P_M$ is nonzero, we may let $b_n = a_{n+M}$ to have $\sum b_n<1/2$ and $P'_N:=\prod_{n=1}^{N}b_n$ converges to nonzero value iff $P_N$ converges to nonzero value.

Comment: @Riemann in the inductive case 1 - S_N <= P_N would be thus make the base-case 2?

Comment: $N = 1$ or $2$ both will work as a base case.

Comment: @Riemann Okay I did the induction with base case 2 and it works. But I don't get why 1 -S <= P_N is even useful? All it's telling us is that P_N is bounded below by 1 - S, but S could be greater than 1, so we don't really gain anything new since we already know that P_N >= 0

Comment: That's why we assumed $S = \sum a_n < 1/2$.

Comment: @Riemann So we get P_N > 1/2, does this give that the product converges, if so, why?

Comment: Since the sequence $P_N$ decrease monotonically and is bounded below by $1/2$.